# Why select() timeouts sometimes when the client is busy receiving data

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sockets, tcp

I have written simple C/S applications to test the characteristics of non-blocking sockets, here is some brief information about the server and client:

```
//On linux The server thread will send 
//a file to the client using non-blocking socket       
void *SendFileThread(void *param){
    CFile* theFile = (CFile*) param;
    int sockfd = theFile->GetSocket();
    set_non_blocking(sockfd);
    set_sock_sndbuf(sockfd, 1024 * 64); //set the send buffer to 64K

    //get the total packets count of target file
    int PacketCOunt = theFile->GetFilePacketsCount();
    int CurrPacket = 0;
    while (CurrPacket < PacketCount){
        char buffer[512];
        int len = 0;

        //get packet data by packet no.
        GetPacketData(currPacket, buffer, len); 

        //send_non_blocking_sock_data will loop and send
        //data into buffer of sockfd until there is error
        int ret = send_non_blocking_sock_data(sockfd, buffer, len);
        if (ret < 0 && errno == EAGAIN){
            continue；
          } else if (ret < 0 || ret == 0 ){
             break;
         } else {
             currPacket++;
         }


         ......
     }
 }
```

```
//On windows, the client thread will do something like below
//to receive the file data sent by the server via block socket
void *RecvFileThread(void *param){
    int sockfd = (int) param; //blocking socket
    set_sock_rcvbuf(sockfd, 1024 * 256); //set the send buffer to 256

    while (1){
        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        fd_set rds;
        FD_ZERO(&rds);
        FD_SET(sockfd, &rds)'

        //actually, the first parameter of select() is 
        //ignored on windows, though on linux this parameter
        //should be (maximum socket value + 1)
        int ret = select(sockfd + 1, &rds, NULL, NULL, &timeout );
        if (ret == 0){
            // log that timer expires
            CLogger::log("RecvFileThread---Calling select() timeouts\n");
        } else if (ret) { 
            //log the number of data it received
            int ret = 0;
            char buffer[1024 * 256];
            int len = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            // handle error
            process_tcp_data(buffer, len);
        } else {
            //handle and break;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

What surprised me is that the server thread fails frequently because of socket buffer full, e.g. to send a file of 14M size it reports 50000 failures with errno = EAGAIN. However, via logging I observed there are tens of timeouts during the transfer, the flow is like below:

1. on the Nth loop, select() succeeds and read 256K's data successfully.
2. on the (N+1)th loop, select() failed with timeout.
3. on the (N+2)th loop, select() succeeds and read 256K's data successfully.

Why there would be timeouts interleaved during the receving? Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

**[UPDATE]**
1. Uploading a file of 14M to the server only takes 8 seconds
2. Using the same file with 1), the server takes nearly 30 seconds to send all data to the client.
3. All sockets used by the client are blocking. All sockets used by the server are non-blocking.

Regarding #2, I think timeouts are the reason why #2 takes much more time then #1, and I wonder why there would be so many timeouts when the client is busy in receiving data.

**[UPDATE2]**
Thanks for comments from @Duck, @ebrob, @EJP, @ja_mesa , I will do more investigation today 
then update this post.
Regarding why I send 512 bytes per loop in the server thread, it is because I found the server thread sends data much faster than the client thread receiving them. I am very confused that why timeout happened to the client thread.

Comment: Why would `GetFilePacketsCount()` have any relationship to `CurrPacket` on the server side?  Isn't the 512 byte buffer a bit arbitrary in length?  Also, on server side it seems you'd get a whole whole bunch of `EAGAIN` but that should be OK as you handle them properly.  Maybe a sleep of some sort on `EAGAIN` would be a good idea?  Wait it looks like GetPacketData consumes data, so you may be creating gaps by calling it more than once for a `EAGAIN`?

Comment: How are you declaring / handling `rds`?  I think you need to FD_SET / FD_ZERO each time round the loop, before you call select(...)

Comment: @ebyrob thanks, I updated the source code. What surprised me is that there are timeouts happened to select call during the period the client thread is busy in receiving data and the server thread reports thousands of EAGAIN failures!

Comment: If you are using nonblocking sockets then it does not wait when data will actually be send. Data is not transeferred instantly, there is some speed limit, thats why you get these timeouts

Comment: @Simon yep!  Both client and server are waiting on the (much slower) network while their processors race ahead with many wait-states...

Comment: EAGAIN isn't a 'failure' in the case of a write: it means that socket send buffer is full. It is an indication that you are writing at maximum speed. Similarly a select() timeout waiting for a socket to become writable means that same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this more of a long comment than an answer but as several people have noted the network is orders of magnitude slower than your processor.  The point of non-blocking i/o is that the difference is so great that you can actually use it to do real work rather than blocking.  Here you are just pounding on the elevator button hoping that makes a difference.

I'm not sure how much of your code is real and how much is chopped up for posting but in the server you don't account for (ret == 0) i.e. normal shutdown by the peer.

The `select` in the client is wrong.  Again, not sure if that was sloppy editing or not but if not then the number of parameters are wrong but, more concerning, the first parameter - i.e. should be the highest file descriptor for select to look at plus one - is zero.  Depending on the implementation of `select` I wonder if that is in fact just turning `select` into a fancy `sleep` statement.

Comment: If he is using MS WinSock the first parameters is ignored and keeps only for compatibility with Berkeley sockets. Anyway, the numbers of parameters is wrong and I also wonder why he use a 1 second timeout and do nothing when select() timed out. He also creates a 256K buffer for every read() while the server is sending in 512 bytes. I think we are provided with tools to be used wisdom and conscientious, otherwise we could end up with this kind of mysterious things.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `recv()` first and then call `select()` only if `recv()` tells you to do so.  Don't call `select()` first, that is a waste of processing.  `recv()` knows if data is immediately available or if it has to wait for data to arrive:

```
void *RecvFileThread(void *param){
    int sockfd = (int) param; //blocking socket
    set_sock_rcvbuf(sockfd, 1024 * 256); //set the send buffer to 256

    char buffer[1024 * 256];

    while (1){

        int ret = 0;
        int len = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (len == -1) {
            if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                //handle error
                break;
            }

            struct timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec = 1;
            timeout.tv_usec = 0;

            fd_set rds;
            FD_ZERO(&rds);
            FD_SET(sockfd, &rds)'

            //actually, the first parameter of select() is 
            //ignored on windows, though on linux this parameter
            //should be (maximum socket value + 1)
            int ret = select(sockfd + 1, &rds, NULL, &timeout );
            if (ret == -1) { 
                // handle error
                break;
            }

            if (ret == 0) {
                // log that timer expires
                break;
            }

            // socket is readable so try read again
            continue;
        }

        if (len == 0) {
            // handle graceful disconnect
            break;
        }

        //log the number of data it received
        process_tcp_data(buffer, len);
    }
}
```

Do something similar on the sending side as well.  Call `send()` first, and then call `select()` waiting for writability only if `send()` tells you to do so.